# UITableViewCell without using deprecated method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have read [Loren's article](http://blog.atebits.com/2008/12/fast-scrolling-in-tweetie-with-uitableview/) on drawing your own content for UITableViewCell. However, he is using a deprecated method: `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` is deprecated on UITableViewCell.

How do you get his example to work without using `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

just had to replace `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:` with the following.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
    {
        // you might want to add the UIView to [self contentView] 
        // so that in edit's the cell's content will be automatically adjusted.
        ABTableViewCellView *myUIView = [[ABTableViewCellView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

        myUIView.opaque = YES;
        contentViewForCell = myUIView;
        [self addSubview:myUIView];
        [myUIView release];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also, apple has an example as Loren points out but they use `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this link to find the replacement for the deprecated method. Should be fairly easy to get the code working with the replacement.
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html

Answer (score 0):

Another be specific way to understand is-
**initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier:**  is deprecated in iOS 3.0. Use **initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier**: instead

Simple Example- 
Error code

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];     
}
```

Expected code

```
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
 cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: When you do this you can run into issues where the cell is there but it's just invisible...

Comment: @AriBraginsky can you please elaborate what you exactly mean by issues and invisible here?