# 'initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier' is deprecated

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I was trying to recreate a Xcode project but I came across an error "'initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier' is deprecated". 
Here is the code:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
    UIView *myContentView = self.contentView;

    self.todoPriorityImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:priority1Image];
    [myContentView addSubview:self.todoPriorityImageView];
    [self.todoPriorityImageView release];

    self.todoTextLabel = [self newLabelWithPrimaryColor:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                          selectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor] fontSize:14.0 bold:YES]; 
    self.todoTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft; // default
    [myContentView addSubview:self.todoTextLabel];
    [self.todoTextLabel release];

    self.todoPriorityLabel = [self newLabelWithPrimaryColor:[UIColor blackColor] 
                                              selectedColor:[UIColor whiteColor] fontSize:10.0 bold:YES];
    self.todoPriorityLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    [myContentView addSubview:self.todoPriorityLabel];
    [self.todoPriorityLabel release];

    // Position the todoPriorityImageView above all of the other views so
    // it's not obscured. It's a transparent image, so any views
    // that overlap it will still be visible.
    [myContentView bringSubviewToFront:self.todoPriorityImageView];
}return self;}
```

I am getting the error on line2 with the start of the if-statement.
This function is clearly not adviceable to use anymore and it now is this function:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {
    // Initialization code.
}
return self;}
```

I don't really know how I can modify the above function and put it in the newer function! Could some1 help me on this matter please?

Thx

Kevin

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell without using deprecated method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815121/uitableviewcell-without-using-deprecated-method-initwithframereuseidentifier)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new initializer is using a [UITableViewCellStryle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UITableViewCellStyle) instead of specifying the frame `CGRect` for the cell and you were just giving the frame to the superclass in `[super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]`. So, there should be not problem to put all the same code in the new version, without the if statement.

You had :

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // all your stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```

You now have :

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // all your stuff
    }
    return self;
}
```