# What is alternative for initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uitableview

Can you help me fix this as the method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier is deprecated:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @”Cell”;

CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {

cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

}
```

Thx in advance,

Stephane

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableViewCell without using deprecated method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815121/uitableviewcell-without-using-deprecated-method-initwithframereuseidentifier)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must use: `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:`

Comment: Well, I don't know how to use UITableViewCellStyle in this case...Any help ?

Comment: Check apple documentation for possible values here the reference http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: initwith style can take following values:    UITableViewCellStyleValue1                  UITableViewCellStyleValue2                UITableViewCellStyleDefault              UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle

Answer (score 3):

a better approach is to define a getter in your CustomCell.m

```
-(NSString*) reuseIdentifier
{
    return @"Cell";
}
```

and in that method you return your reuse identifier.
Then you can alternatively create yourself a setter for a variable as well thereby allowing you to have any set of custom cells with whatever reuse identifier you plan to use.

another method that includes the reuse identifier and is not depreciated is

```
[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other answers, here's one thing you're doing which sticks out as not right:

```
cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Calling [CustomCell alloc] implies you have subclassed UITableViewCell and are using your own init method that you coded in there (and I know this is not the case by reading the rest of your question).

You might possibly mean to change that line to:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleWhatever reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

You don't need to use initWithFrame as the cell's frame is decided by the width of the UITableView it's a part of and the height you pass in heightForRowAtIndexPath in the UITableView's data source methods.