# initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier is deprecated and initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UITableViewCell without using deprecated method initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815121/uitableviewcell-without-using-deprecated-method-initwithframereuseidentifier)

My project had a custom `UITableViewCell` with custom height, previously we used `initWithFrame:reuseIdentifier`, but the function is deprecated, so I used `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` but now no cells are visible.

I used `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` as the cell style.

Comment: better you should post the code here. that will be easy to understand the problems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815121/uitableviewcell-without-using-deprecated-method-initwithframereuseidentifier?rq=1

Comment: Thanks.. Prince  i resolved it by adding `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` in custom class